# Cannot resolve symbol 'android' in Import

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I am getting error in Android Studio. My import:

```
imports com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
```

are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

instead of import**s** to import a class.

Answer (score 0):

Download new version of google-play-services library.
Always update/download newest version of google-play-services library.

Answer (score 0):

you must add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
```

in dependencies block, in app/build.gradle.
also update google play in sdk manager